# What can be the reason for the following error

Tags: javascript, jquery

Using jQuery Ajax to fetch data from local server: it works well with IE8 but with Firefox4 it goes wrong: (entering error function with just "error" message). Firebug shows the data is getting correct.

The running URL is:
http://localhost:47092/testajax

The related jQuery code is:

```
  $.ajax(
        {
            type: "GET",
            url: "http://localhost/test",
            processData: true,
            data: {},
            dataType: "json",
            success: function (data, code, jqx) {
                console.log(data);
            },
            error: function (jqx, err, ex) {
                console.log(ex);
            }
        }
    );
```

What can be the cause of the error? I am using jQuery 1.5.2

Also, I am using jQuery.support.cors = true to enable cross domain scripting.

Comment: Note that `console.log` will be undefined unless Firebug is open.

Comment: The domain 'localhost' does not existing in the Internet.^^ It is only accesable locally.

Comment: I don't think anyone will be able to view your linked test site `http://localhost:47092/testajax` ...

Comment: console.log works fine in FF4, the Web Console offers per-tab logging.

Comment: `http://localhost...` classic.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Sounds like you ran into a cross-site-scripting protection.

```
http://localhost:47092/testajax
http://localhost/test
```

The protocol, the hostname, and the port has to be identical. Otherwise you have to use a solution like JSONP.

Comment: you are correct, but I am wondering  jQuery.support.cors = true  does not work with Firefox 4

Comment: `jQuery.support.cors` is a read-only attribute - you can't enable stuff using it, its purpose is feature-detection. Did you implement CORS (and the respective HTTP headers) on the server-side of `http://localhost/test`? https://developer.mozilla.org/en/http_access_control

Answer (score 0):

localhost:47092 is different than localhost. Use relative URLs in the Ajax call, not absolute ones.